# Converting Video File(s) to GIF

Tags: python, gif, python-3.8

I want make a converter based on python 3.8

I'm using imageoi API 2.6.1

Here's some of my codes what i think i did it wrong

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import imageio
import os

root = Tk()
ftypes = [('All Files', "*.*"), ('Webm', "*.webm")]
ttl = "Select Files(s)"
dir1 = 'D:/My Pictures/9gag'
root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=ftypes, initialdir=dir1, title=ttl)
lst = list(root.fileName)


def path_leaf(path):
    return path.strip('/').strip('\\').split('/')[-1].split('\\')[-1]


print([path_leaf(path) for path in lst])
lst2 = [path_leaf(path) for path in lst]
print(lst)


def gifMaker(inputPath, targetFormat):
    outputPath = os.path.splitext(inputPath)[0] + targetFormat
    print(f'converting {inputPath} \n to {outputPath}')

    reader = imageio.get_reader(inputPath)
    fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps']

    writer = imageio.get_writer(outputPath, fps=fps)

    for frames in reader:
        writer.append_data(frames)
        print(f'Frame {frames}')
    print('Done!')
    writer.close()


for ad in lst2:
    gifMaker(ad, '.gif')
```

And the error are shown like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/My Pictures/GIF/GIF.py", line 41, in <module>
    gifMaker(ad, '.gif')
  File "D:/My Pictures/GIF/GIF.py", line 28, in gifMaker
    reader = imageio.get_reader(inputPath)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 173, in get_reader
    request = Request(uri, "r" + mode, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 126, in __init__
    self._parse_uri(uri)
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\request.py", line 278, in _parse_uri
    raise FileNotFoundError("No such file: '%s'" % fn)
FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'D:\My Pictures\GIF\a6VOVL2_460sv.mp4'
```

So, what am i missing or fault? I don't understand why the error is showing "file is not found". Can someone explain to me in detail, how these lines of error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities
 Maybe you misstyped the path/filename. 
Maybe the space in the path is causing trouble.

Comment: I tried use basic path like C: or D:, and it's still not working.

Comment: Try to open a simple text file first. Then break down your script into smaller part. Put a file like test.mp4 in the same directory as the script and the just try to open that. If that is working expand ypur code from there.